# Python: No such file or directory

Tags: python

I am receiving an error message about No such file or directory for my python code. I save the file on my desktop computer. But I am receiving the error message

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
fh=open("C:/Users/****/Desktop/IP Data","r")
for line in fh.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        words = line.split()
# increase counters
for word in words: 
            if len(words)>3:
                if "IP" in words[1]:
                    print '%s\t%s' % (words[2],1)
```

Comment: try making it a raw string as in `r"C:/Users/****/Desktop/IP Data"`

Comment: @BhargavRao, Are you talking about like this:fh=open("r C:/Users/****/Desktop/IP Data","r")

Comment: @BhargavRao, I am receiving the same error. I have my program in a Virtual Box that have windows 7. I install python 2.7

Comment: Try this `r'C:\\Users\***\Desktop\IP Data'` Note the double back slash after `C:`

Comment: @BhargavRao, I have a new error: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:

Comment: @BhargavRao, I got it . I change it to:"C:\\Users\****\Desktop\IP Data",'r'

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant to say! Add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use backslashes in windows. Try changing to `C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\IP Data`

Comment: Vama, I am receiving the same error. I have my program in a Virtual Box that have windows 7. I install python 2.7

Comment: If you're working in cmd.exe then yes, but if you're working in Python then you can use either.

Comment: Backslashes are good, but they shall be escaped to end up in the string, shouldn't they? `"C:\\Users\\..."`

Comment: @flaschbier yes they should be escaped. Or the string could be declared raw.

Comment: @SakshamVarma it was just a hint that you might want to edit your answer ;)